# How to find all the servers on local network?

Tags: ios, sockets, networking, gcdasyncsocket, cocoaasyncsocket

I'm using CocoaAsyncSocket for a server client application on the iPad. Right now if the server is up the client can type in the IP of the server and connect to it. Is there a way to display all the servers on the local network that are running this app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking up devices in own network is easily realized by using **zeroconf/bonjour** service.

The **servers** have to run the service and tell the **service-name**. This can be **filtered by the client app**.

I cannot promise, but maybe you find something usefull in my question times ago: [Clean solution for lookup if extern IP is in own subnet range in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10278098/883799) (care, this code will **not compile for arm64** architecture and has to be reworked)